# Use DefaultAzureCredentials to authenticate Service bus in Docker Container

Tags: azure, docker, azureservicebus, servicebus, defaultazurecredential

I'm trying to use `DefaultAzureCredentials` to authenticate my Azure function against Azure Service Bus. In my azure function `azure-func-service-bus`, I call to Azure Service Bus

```
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(
    fully_qualified_namespace=MY_SERVICE_BUS_NAMESPACE_NAME+".servicebus.windows.net",
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=['*'])
)
```

I created and pushed Docker container to ACR. When I run the container locally for testing outside of Azure, it does not know what permissions to use.

```
az acr login --name acr01 
docker push acr01.azurecr.io/azure-func-service-bus:v1
docker pull acr01.azurecr.io/azure-func-service-bus:v1
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 acr01.azurecr.io/azure-func-service-bus:v1
```

but got the following error.

```
    DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
    ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
    SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
    VisualStudioCodeCredential: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.
    AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path
    AzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed
To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.
Unexpected error occurred (ClientAuthenticationError('DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.\nAttempted credentials:\n\tEnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.\nVisit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.\n\tManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.\n\tSharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.\n\tVisualStudioCodeCredential: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.\n\tAzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path\n\tAzurePowerShellCredential: PowerShell is not installed\nTo mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.')). Handler shutting down.
```

I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

When the Azure Function runs in Azure, it's configured to support ManagedIdentityCredential. For your case I'd recommend trying to configure [EnvironmentCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet) to test locally.

You can find the details in the link, but the short version is:

1. Create a service principle ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli)) and give it the needed access
2. Run the container with extra Environment Variables:
   AZURE_TENANT_ID: service principal's Tenant ID
   AZURE_CLIENT_ID: service principal's AppId
   AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: service principle's password

I'd recommend using a .env file to make this easier, but be sure it doesn't get checked in anywhere.

FYI If your account doesn't use MFA, you can instead use the variables AZURE_USERNAME and AZURE_PASSWORD. But then you've put your username and password in a file or your terminal history which is concerning. Admittedly the service principal has the same problem, but you can more easily mitigate that with minimizing it's access and regularly rolling the secret.

P.S. If you're using Visual Studio for making your Azure Function you should be able to use something like: [EnvironmentCredentialExample](https://github.com/NCarlsonMSFT/EnvironmentCredentialExample) to automate setting up and using the needed .env file.